# How to make this delivery log populate each row with a customers details from the list of customers by simply searching the name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been using a spreadsheet delivery log on Google sheet to prepare my weekly deliveries. I have a list of about 200 regular customers who i deliver to weekly. I've been manually adding the customer by firstly doing a Ctrl/F to search for the customers name, and then copy/pasting the row onto the deliver log. Once I've completed my list, i use google maps to optimise the delivery order and then i sort sheet range by A/z so that its in numerical order. As you can see, its a laborious and repetitive process.

I've attached a copy of the delivery log i'm currently using along with a tab of a list of customers (however, it's in excel format, i normally use google sheets).

[Delivery Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUCAt.jpg)
[image]
[List of Customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43QUF.jpg)
[image]

I wanted to use Apps Script on Google Sheets to make the process automated. To be able to search the customers name on the delivery log which then gives me the list of possible options from my list of customers until i can isolate the customer after typing his/her full name and then once i click on the name it populates the row on the delivery log with the Name, Address, Post code, Tel/Mob, and Additional Info.

As you can tell, i am a complete newbie to the coding world. I've spent the last week searching on Youtube for any help with how i can go about making this possible. I would genuinely appreciate any help. I don't expect anyone to do the work for me, i will glad work on it myself, i just desperately need help with a YouTube clip or any reference source that can help me with this task.

Answer (score 0):

### SUGGESTION

We can try to create a script using the [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) function to automate information filling in the delivery logs sheet using Apps Script. Some key notes to point out:

1. The script gets the list of names on the delivery logs sheet, which are then compared to the list of names in the customer database sheet.
2. If a match is found, the script automatically triggers (with the onEdit() function) and fills in the other information of that customer from the customer database.
3. (Optional) I used a drop-down list to list down all the customer names available from the database sheet, however since you mentioned that you have at least 200 customers attended weekly, managing all those names using a drop-down may not be feasible.

**You can use this sample script provided below for your reference:**

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var logs = ss.getSheetByName("Delivery Log");
  var db = ss.getSheetByName("List of Customers");

  // gets the list of customer names from the delivery logs
  var logVals = logs.getRange(2, 2, logs.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  // gets the customer database data
  var dbNames = db.getRange(2, 1, db.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  var dbData = db.getRange(2, 2, db.getLastRow() - 1, db.getLastColumn()-1).getValues();

  // this for loop checks if a customer's name is listed on 
  // the customer database information
  for (i = 0; i < logVals.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < dbNames.length; j++) {
      // if a match is found, all the information from the customer database
      // is auto-populated beside the customer's name on the delivery log
      if (logVals[i] == dbNames[j][0]) {
        logs.getRange(i + 2, 3, 1, dbData[j].length).setValues([dbData[j]]);
        break;
      }
      // if the cell box is left blank, or no match is found
      // the other columns are left empty
      else
        logs.getRange(i + 2, 3, 1, 3).clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Once you've saved the script, you can proceed to work on your delivery logs sheet as you normally would; the script will automatically be triggered via the onEdit() function, to perform the auto-filling of information.

### UPDATE

With regards to the usage of a drop-down list for your "auto-search" functionality on your customer database, you can instead type in the name normally instead of scrolling through the drop-down list, and the  drop-down will automatically filter the names to those similar with your real-time entry, until an exact match is found (see output image below).

Also, just to provide additional information on [how you can create a dynamic drop-down list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103) (which automatically updates your user database onto the drop-down list), here are some additional steps:

1. On Google Sheets, you can go to **Data > Data Validation** to open the Data Validation rules on the right side. Click on "Add Rule", and do as follows:
2. Under "Apply to range", you can select the range where the drop-down lists are to be applied, so it should be on Column B in "Delivery Logs"
3. Under "Criteria", select "Dropdown (from a range)", and select the range as `='List of Customers'!A2:A`, or all the customer's name within the customer database; this also ensures that any new entry will automatically be included in the drop-down.
4. After that, you can save the rule, and the drop-down lists should appear on Column B in the "Delivery Logs" sheet.

### OUTPUT

[image]

### REFERENCES

You can check out the following links for more information about the other functions used in the script:

- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question, or if there are some clarifications needed so that I can adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Mic Test, thank you so much for your response., i genuinely appreciate your help. It was slightly tricky to isolate the customer from a drop-down list of 200 customers. I wonder, is it possible to search the name of the customer (by first name or surname) and the list narrows down until there is a perfect name match...and then it populates the row with all the details?

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know of that. So with regards to drop-down lists, while you usually scroll through the list of entries to find the correct customer name, you can instead just type on the drop-down list and it should work similarly to a "search bar", wherein it will give you the suggested names included in your database, until you are able to find the exact match.

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional info; let me know if you have any further questions so that we can clarify it up.

Comment: Hi Mic Test. Apologies for asking yet another silly question. So i attempted your sample script above on my original spreadsheet - the one i personally use - but i couldn't get it to work. I can't see what i'm doing wrong. Would you mind if i shared the file with you to have a look please?

Comment: I see; sure thing, that would be much better if you can provide a sample of the sheet you are using so that we can check further what the problem is.

Comment: Sure thing, thank you for providing the link; though it seems that since this may be the main sheet you are working on, how about we create a copy of this and then you can provide access to that instead? That way, any important information on your main sheet is kept safe.

Comment: That would be amazing, thank you!!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qfeC0fTuX5AamwuXNy9LgxkairmWanCzvrycpq6CGnU/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi Mic Test, sorry to bother you again, any chance of a bit more help?